# Issue with .populate() on array of arrays in Mongoose Model

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently having troubles with .populate() on my model for an array of arrays of dictionaries. I'm pushing the user's cart (an array of dictionaries) into the user's history (an array of arrays). I want to be able to show the product information for the user's past carts/purchase history.

It's not getting through to the second level of inside the array matrix to the dictionaries where it can populate the actual model and not just show the dictionary. The issue is coming through where I have no way to call each array separately or as if in a loop. Here is the model and controller function:

```
// User Model
mongoose.model("User", new mongoose.Schema({
...
    cart:[ { "item":{ type:ObjectId, ref:"Product" }, "quantity": {type:Number, required:true}} ],
    history:[ [{ "item":{ type:ObjectId, ref:"Product" }, "quantity": {type:Number, required:true}}] ], // array of cart arrays
...
));

//User Controller
User.find({_id:req.params.id})
.populate({
    model:"Product",
    path:"cart.item", // this works just fine
    populate: {
        model: "Product",
        path: "history.item" // this has no effect (obviously, should be something like history.x.item to iterate through the arrays in history)
    }
})
.exec((err, userArray)=> {
    if(err) {
        res.json({errors: "Could not find user"});
    }
    else {
        let user = userArray[0];
        console.log(user.history)               
        res.json(user);
    }
});
```

The .populate() works properly on the cart attribute and does pull from the designated Product model as seen below. This is what I want it to be doing for each array for each array inside the history.

```
// user.cart.item;
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {
    item: { // .populate() executed correctly here
        createdAt: "2018-05-01T19:01:13.439Z"
        desc: "Marine Layer - Summer Tunic"
        inventory: 3
        name: "Bali Tunic"
        photosrc: "tunic.jpg"
        price: 88
        updatedAt: "2018-05-17T21:33:01.121Z"
        _id: "5ae8b9790a739c3a6409c6ca"
    }
    quantity:1
    _id:"5afdf50ddb9d9131bc31f79f"
}
1: { item: {…}, quantity: 2, _id: "5afdf512db9d9131bc31f7a0" }
```

It does not work on the history since user.history.item does not exist on the model - needs a for loop or something to iterate through the indexes of the history array first before calling .populate():

```
// user.history.item:
(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0:Array(2)
    0:{
        item: "5ae8b9790a739c3a6409c6ca", //not populating here
        quantity: 2,
        _id: "5af24260dce6852f10cb7937"
    }
    1:{ item: "5ae8ea78fc63980820a88478", quantity: 3, _id: "5af24266dce6852f10cb7938"}
1:(2) [{…}, {…}]
2:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
3:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
4:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I've tried restructuring a variety of ways, but still get the same results. Any insight would be much appreciated!